# In c# using StreamWriter to write to AZURE can i use the URI as the path

Tags: azure, streamwriter

I am using nuGet CsvHelper to write a datatable to a new CSV file. It works fine with path of a physical location Ie C:/temp/mydrop box. But I need it to streamwrite to a Azure Storage container.
when the program gets to here
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);
I get the following error:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\sample\bin\Debug\net6.0\https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer-processedfiles/myfle.csv''

I am passing in https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer-processedfiles/myfle.csv